# Xamarin.Essentials; FilePicker; Save a new file

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

Using [FilePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) one can open an existing file:

```
         FileResult file = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
         TextView textview = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textview);
         string path = file.FullPath;
         var handle = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
         byte[] data = new byte[10];
         handle.Read(data, 0, 10);
```

Is there a similar way for saving a new file?

Comment: You have access to all of the normal `File` class methods. Checkout this link for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: As far as I know, there are no direct ways to do this, You have to manually go ahead and do the saving part natively.Check : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the FilePicker plugin is only designed to pick existing files.

On Android and iOS, you could not do that. But on UWP, you could use the `FileSavePicker`.

Xamarin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android

UWP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-save-a-file-with-a-picker